# How does my Defined Contribution pension plan work?

Tags: united-states, retirement-plan, 403b, pension-plan

I am a new employee and I was wondering if someone can help me understand what this defined contribution retirement plan means for me.

My org says after 1 year of service with 1000 hours and being 21 I can participate in the defined contribution retirement plan. The contribution schedule at first is:

- 0-5 years of vesting service = 3.5%
- 6-10 years of vesting = 4.5
- 11+ = 6%

Then for the 403b retirement it says after 2 years of employment 500 hours and age 21 I am eligible for that. It says 50% of the first 3% employee contribution (1.5%). I'm 100% vested after 2 years 500 hours.

What is the defined contribution? I currently am funding my retirement Roth 403b and contributing 15%.

Comment: You might want to be slightly more verbose. I assume your last paragraph means you're funding a Roth IRA ?

Comment: Shouldn't evaluating and understanding the compensation you'll receive come *before* you accept the job?

Answer (score 1):

A [defined contribution plan](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/d/definedcontributionplan.asp) is simply an employee-sponsored retirement plan where you and/or your employer can specify the *contribution amount*, and the *benefit* (what you get when you retire) is not defined (i.e., it's based on market returns and whatever you want to take out).  A 401(k) and a 403(b) are kinds of defined contribution plans.

This is as opposed to a *defined benefit* plan, such as a pension, where you are given a particular *benefit* (such as, "$500 a month for life once you turn 65").

In your case, it's possible that your employer has two different options for a defined contribution plan.  One that the employer self-funds, and one that the employer matches your contributions. That's uncommon, but particularly in companies with very many young employees is not that rare; in fact, my company has a contribution plan where it contributes the entire amount and doesn't require us to contribute anything (but we still can, just with no match).

So it sounds like you get 3.5% of your salary until you're with the company 5 years put into a 403(b) type plan, then higher amounts after that, *plus* whatever you contribute matched up to 3% (so 1.5%).  So if you fully participated and contributed 3%, you'd get an additional 5% for years 3-5, an additional 6% for years 6-10, and an additional 7.5% from years 11+.

Comment: So if I am getting this right. Say I am annually contributing 15% to my plan. Year 1: will be: just my 15%. Year 2 will be 18.5%, year 3 will be 20%? year 7: 21%                                        I am getting these numbers by adding the them to the 15%?

Comment: I think year 1 will be 16.5%, year 2-5 will be 20%, year 6-10 will be 21%, and year 11+ will be 22.5%.  You're getting the 1.5% the whole time; *vested* in that sense means that you'd have to stay employed for the 2 year period to *keep* that 1.5% after you leave.  So as long as you stay 2+ years/500+ hours/whatever the rules are, you get that 1.5% the whole time.

Comment: "My org says after 1 year of service with 1000 hours and being 21 I can participate in the defined contribution retirement plan."  But since I don't have 1 year of service yet I only get the 15% that I am contributing since right now I have not been there a year? Correct?

Comment: Oh, I may have misread the other part. You may have it right.

Answer (score 0):

Contribution is what you're putting into your 401(k) from your paycheck. You spend 3% of every paycheck and your company pays an additional 50% of that into your 401(k)